# How do I shorten this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I would like to allow the string to start with capital letters and the first two characters should **not** contain **NL** but other alphabets like **DE, BE** etc..

Here is how I do it in javascript

```
str.substring(0,2).match(/^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ]+[ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]+$/)
```

I would like to shorten it to ranges. I tried with these range expressions [A-MO-Z], [A-M][O-Z]+ but non of them work.

Edit:
I tried these expressions but they don't work

```
str.substring(0,2).match(/^[A-MO-Z]+[A-KM-Z]+$/)
str.substring(0,2).match(/^[A-M][O-Z]+[A-K][M-Z]+$/)
str.substring(0,2).match(/^([A-M][O-Z])+([A-K][M-Z])+$/)
```

Comment: "but non of them work." --- please demonstrate it doesn't

Comment: `str.substring(0,2).match(/^[A-MO-Z]+[A-KM-Z]+$/)` -- it's identical to your original expression. And it works like your original expression.

Comment: Wouldn't the code be easier for the reader (the poor sap who has to maintain this) if you simply compared the first two characters to 'NL', and then followed that (as necessary) with a simple `/^[A-Z]+$/`? What happens when 'ME' is added to the disallowed list? What's that regular expression going to look like? (On the other hand, if it was hard to write, then maybe it should be hard to read, hard to debug, and hard to change.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - That's the approach I would take, even though Paulpro's answer is more elegant. Most JS programmers I know don't know more advanced parts of the regex syntax, so I try to avoid them where possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a prime use case for a negative look ahead:

```
str.match(/^(?!NL)[A-Z]{2}/)
```

Note that this will allow `NA, NB, NC, ...` and `AL, BL, CL, ...`, just not `NL` specifically.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution but it's not working. Gives null for both NL and other alphabets.

Comment: For the benefit of those of us that might need to called upon to read this, and possibly change this, in the future, would you mind including a comment line that explains what this is doing. (First two characters don't match 'NL', and entire string is uppercase alphabetic.) Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2335977 - `/^(?!NL)[A-Z]{2}/.test("NL") === false && /^(?!NL)[A-Z]{2}/.test("DE") === true`. That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: I don't know why but right now the expression [A-Z]{2} is not working for me. I tried this and it works /^(?!NL)[A-Z]+[A-Z]+/ Don't know what could be the reason. Thanks anyways. :-)

Comment: @user2335977 `[A-Z]+[A-Z]+` means `[A-Z]{2,}` as in two or more characters rather than exactly two like I put in my answer.

Comment: Alright. Thank you :-) I was trying on the whole string instead of substring, that could be the reason it did not work.